# How to use ISDATE function in Pervasive SQL SELECT statement

Tags: pervasive-sql

can someone please tell me how to use the ISDATE function in a Pervasive SQL SELECT statement?

I tried to find an example, but they all show something like:
ISDATE('12/31/2020'), with a literal date string; I need to check a column name.

I'm trying the following:
SELECT CustId, ProductId, Price, EffectiveDate, ISDATE(EffectiveDate) FROM Ar_CustPrice2
but getting "...Error in expression ISDATE(EffectiveDate)"

Thanks

Comment: What version of PSQL are you using?  I can't find any reference in the Pervasive / Actian documentation of an ISDATE function.

Comment: What examples did you consult? What is the type and content of `EffectiveDate` column?

Comment: Engine version is 11.2

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an ISDATE function available for Pervasive PSQL v11.  There is no documentation or examples showing it for Pervasive PSQL.

Comment: Here's the schema; EffectiveDate is a "DATE" field
CREATE TABLE "Ar_CustPrice2"(
 "CustId" VARCHAR(15),
 "ProductId" VARCHAR(30),
 "Price" MONEY(15,4),
 "EffectiveDate" DATE,
 "EndDate" DATE,
 "Status" BIT,
 "DiscPct" DOUBLE,
 "SalesAccountId" VARCHAR(24),
 "CreatedBy" VARCHAR(3),
 "CreatedDate" DATE,
 "UpdatedBy" VARCHAR(3),
 "UpdatedDate" DATE,
 "UnUsed" VARCHAR(49));

Comment: ok, I probably pulled up a SQL Server reference by mistake. Let me start from the beginning. A MS Access query that had been working up to 3 days ago started bombing out with the "invalid date, time, or timestamp value" error. Working through it, I found that this "EffectiveDate" field evidently was the culprit. I need to find the rows with bad EffectiveDate values, and get them out of there. Hence the need for something like "ISDATE".

Comment: To further clarify, I'm an 8/10 in MS Access, a 4/10 in SQL Server, and 0/10 in Pervasive SQL, and the Pervasive Control Center.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. This Pervasive db is used by an accounting app that evidently doesn't have very tight editing; it allowed a user to enter a date value of "12/1/20121". and it was causing the blow-up of the MS ODBC driver. Thanks for your responses.
https://communities.actian.com/s/article/How-can-I-fix-Invalid-Dates-within-my-Pervasive-data-files5129